# how to use parenthesis in Laravel SQL raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to build a query where an user need his/her correct `username` or `email` and `password` to login.

Here is my Laravel query code

```
$query = Adminuser::where('password',$password);
$query->orWhere('email',$username);        
$query->where('username',$username);
```

By using this I got the raw SQL query like

```
select * from `adminuser` where `password` = $password and `email` = $username or `username` = $username
```

But I need the raw SQL query like to get the proper result

```
select * from `adminuser` where `password` = $password and (`email` = $username or `username` = $username)
```

So my question is how to use the parenthesis in my laravel query?

Anyone help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use grouping. Please read more: [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping) ([Laravel 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres)).

Your query should like this(not tested):

EDIT:

```
Model::where(function ($query) use ($password) {
    $query->where('password',$password);
})->where(function ($query) use (email, $password){
    $query->where('email',$email)
          ->orWhere('username',$username);
});
```

Comment: you may add the password part to it but the query is correct

Comment: @DhavalChheda thanks for pointing out the typo. I have edited my answer. TY

Comment: elegant-user ... Here told that 'Undefined variable : password' ...But I already define it !

Comment: @Arafat I see you need to use parameter grouping in the query to acheive you goal. You will need to play around in order to resolve other issues like hwat you are seeing.

Comment: @Arafat of course you can use raw method to insert raw expression as demonstrated here in the official documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: @elegant-user.... Whenever a variable is used in the query function they called it 'undefined variable'

Comment: @Arafat Ok. I have updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: @ elegant-user....At last it works !! Little bit change needed in your updated code. I have changed it....Thanks a lot brother :)

Comment: @Arafat More than happy to help bro :) . TY

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = Adminuser::where('password',$password)->where(function($query) use ($username){
$query->orWhere(['email' => $username, 'username' => $username])
})->first();
```

Comment: Whenever a variable is used in the query function they called it 'undefined variable'.
Using your query I got 'undefined variable:password'

Comment: @pravin dabhi 1+ for use ($username) in your answer. TY